# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Но не нужно просто их выписывать, гораздо важнее выделить главные для себя мысли, основополагающие убеждения.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, знаки поставлены корректно. Можно рассмотреть еще вариант с двоеточием после "выписывать" (если считать, что вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой), но я бы предпочел запятую, избегая сильных акцентов.